# NullPointerException while using GridViewPager class on Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a problem with using GridViewPager for Android Wear. When adding it to my layout Android Studio says that there is no such class (Null Pointer Exception). What am I doing wrong? I'm  using Android Studio 0.8.2 and I have choosen Wear application via wizard. 
Here is my code:

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MyActivity"
tools:deviceIds="wear_square">

<android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and my error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: eu.nalewczynski.weargsdgs, PID: 10653
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.populate(GridViewPager.java:900)
        at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.populate(GridViewPager.java:848)
        at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.onMeasure(GridViewPager.java:1141)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.onMeasure(WatchViewStub.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2321)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1145)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1340)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1032)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5657)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My full java code is barely untouched:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

GridViewPager gvp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            //blahblahblah
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: The populate method can suggest that there is something wrong with children (null children) or adapter, but you haven't set any adapter to your GridViewPager.
I'm not at home right now, so I cannot test it, but can you please try to set any adapter (may be empty) to GridViewPager? ViewPager can work without any adapter, but maybe GridViewPager cannot (and throws NullPointerException).

Comment: This is just by not setting an adapter. Please see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `NullPointerException` is not for the case when class cannot be found - there is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` for that. `NullPointerException` occures when a method is invoked on a variable that is null.

```
Object nullString = null;
nullString.toString() // <- will throw NullPointerException;
```

Second thing: you need to learn how to read a stacktrace:

You can see some methods being invoked on `GridViewPager` class. This clearly means that this class is present and CAN be found.

```
    at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.populate(GridViewPager.java:900)
    at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.populate(GridViewPager.java:848)
    at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.onMeasure(GridViewPager.java:1141)
```

Your real problem is not in your xml layout, but rather in Java code. Please post your full java code (activity, adapter etc.) in order to receive some help with your problem.

---

### EDIT

I've tested this issue and I've managed to reproduce the same stacktrace when I've added just a GridViewPager without any adapter. I've also checked the case when a adapter is set:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final GridViewPager gridViewPager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.gridViewPager);
        gridViewPager.setAdapter(new MyGridViewPagerAdapter());
    }

    private class MyGridViewPagerAdapter extends GridPagerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void destroyItem(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1, int arg2, Object arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount(int arg0) {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine now.
Whats surprising `GridViewPager` throws exceptions when either `getColumnCount` or `getRowCount` returns 0... So does it means that we cannot have a valid "empty" adapter? :\
Stacktrace for 0 in `getColumnCount` or `getRowCount`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.wearable.view.BackgroundController.getBackground(BackgroundController.java:204)
    at android.support.wearable.view.BackgroundController.onVerticalScroll(BackgroundController.java:240)
    at android.support.wearable.view.BackgroundController.setPage(BackgroundController.java:91)
    at android.support.wearable.view.BackgroundController.setAdapter(BackgroundController.java:51)
    at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.setAdapter(GridViewPager.java:445)
    at com.example.compressiontest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
    ... 11 more
```

**Bonus story**: This is just another weird situation with wearable UI support lib. Another thing is `WearableListView` that throws `NullPointerException` (when clicking on top empty space) when you didn't set `setClickListener`) :\
 More info here: https://plus.google.com/115773092852757402019/posts/KBZUJwA6CPT